# Pyppeteer query page contents after timeout?

Tags: google-chrome, web, web-crawler, puppeteer, pyppeteer

After navigating to a page, I would like to wait for either:

1. The page to load, OR
2. A timeout (20 seconds)

However, after catching a TimeoutError, it reports that the original page has crashed and I cannot retrieve the contents.

Is it possible to hit a timeout but then query the page contents?